# Why does RavenDB EmbeddableDocumentStore depend on the Raven.Database assembly?

Tags: ravendb

I am trying to use the `Raven.Client.Embedded.EmbeddableDocumentStore` (Build 960) in a Unit Test project, like this:

```
private IDocumentStore CreateDocumentStore()
{
    var store = new EmbeddableDocumentStore
    {
            RunInMemory = true,
            Conventions = new DocumentConvention
            {
                    DefaultQueryingConsistency = ConsistencyOptions.QueryYourWrites,
                    IdentityPartsSeparator = "-"
            }
    };
    store.Initialize();
    IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(typeof (RavenIndexes).Assembly, store);
    return store;
}
```

I installed the following RavenDB components via NuGet:

- RavenDB.Embedded
- RavenDB.Client

The code above fails because it cannot locate the Raven.Database 1.0.0.0 assembly. To fix this I installed the RavenDB.Database package via nuget as well. This added a whole stack of stuff I didn't want, which is to be expected given the [nuget description](http://nuget.org/packages?q=RavenDB.Database) of this package:

> Use this package if you want extend RavenDB. Don't use this package if
>   you just want to work with existing RavenDB server, in order to so
>   just use the client API which is in the RavenDB.Client package.

Now when I try to uninstall the RavenDB.Database package using NuGet it tells me I cannot:

> Uninstall-Package : Unable to uninstall 'RavenDB.Database 1.0.960'
>   because 'RavenDB.Embedded 1.0.960' depends on it.

So what to do? Do I mess up my NuGet purity and manually remove all the unused references (`RavenDB.Smuggler` etc) from my unit test project leaving only the `RavenDB.Database` reference? Or have I gone amiss somewhere? Surely the `EmbeddableDocumentStore` does not require me to install the entire RavenDB.Database package.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Embeddable depends on Database because when you're running Embeddable you're running the whole database server engine within your app and the Database package contains that engine.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Perhaps there could be a slimmed down NuGet package for those who just want to run an in-memory database (for unit-testing typically) as opposed to have all the bells and whistles.